# c copy struct with pointers from stack to heap

Tags: c, heap-memory

Given the following type

```
typedef struct {
  const void *data;
  uint32_t offset[2];
} TSNode;
```

I've got a function which contains an assignement:

```
TSNode* myFun() {
    TSNode node = get_node();
    // rest of code
}
```

Since `node` is allocated on stack memory here, it'll vanish once the function has ended. I want to keep track of that node at later points, so I thought to just copy it to the heap.

```
TSNode* myFun() {
    TSNode node = get_node();

    TSNode* heapNode = malloc(sizeof(TSNode));
    memcpy(heapNode, &node, sizeof(TSNode));
    return heapNode;
}
```

Does this memcpy all data correctly to my heap allocated `heapNode`?
i.e. nothing is corrupted in the process & the `*data` is intact?

Comment: what this function do `get_node();` ?

Comment: Answer is yes. What makes you think `memcpy` would corrupt anything? But this is somewhat odd, please show `get_node()`, depending on that you might need to do things differently alltogether.

Comment: it's pseudo_code for a function which returns a root node from an ast.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I was somehow under the impression I had to manually copy each field to a new struct here & couldn't just memcpy the whole thing.

Comment: No, `memcpy` just copies the whole struct byte per byte and this is exactly what we want. Manually copying each field is also possible, but it's slower and error prone.

Comment: You just encountered the rationale for copy constructors in C++!

Comment: By the way, there is no need to memcpy. Simply assign: `*heapnode = node;`. I think that was part of the first ANSI C version (The original Kernighan/Ritchie C allowed only two things with a struct: Applying the `.` operator and the `&` operator. No assignment, no parameter passing). That is, it has been available for 39 years. I feel old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this memcpy all data correctly to my heap allocated heapNode? i.e. nothing is corrupted in the process & the *data is intact?

The answer to this question is, `memcpy` use `shallow copy` concept. In `shallow copy` the pointer in your original structure (node) `TSNode node = get_node();` will be copied to the new node `heapNode` (`TSNode* heapNode`) bit by bit also call bit wise copy. So your new `heapNode` pointers will also pointing to the same location as your original node's (`TSNode node = get_node();`) pointers from where you copied the value with `memcpy`.  Hence once control returns from function  `myFun` your original node will be released from memory. Therefore your new node pointers will become `dangling pointers`. That is a critical side effect of `memcpy`.

Comment: On the other hand, the `data` pointer member is a `const` pointer, so it is probably pointing to constant data that should not be deallocated.

Comment: So if the `const void *data` wasn't constant, I would need to make a deep copy?

Comment: Whether `data` gets invalid after returning from the function depends on the content that is assigned by `get_node`. The returned pointer itself will not become dangling anyway.

Comment: @DavidRTribble, Good catch. Even though it is a const pointer it will not be a const anymore.

Comment: @Seneca, Use deep copy concept

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Seneca, if *data is non const, you need to free it before leaving the function. Shallow copy will avoid this. With *data being const, you don't need to free it but then also shallow copy will not harm.