# Is it good practice to copy objects from the stack to the heap by setting a dereferenced pointer?

Tags: c, stack, heap-memory

Please consider this sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
} X;

int main(void) {
  X* p = malloc(sizeof(X)); // Heap allocation
  X z = {.a = 2, .b = 3}; // Stack allocation
  *p = z; // Copying from the stack onto the heap

  printf("\n%d\n", p->b);

  return 0;
}
```

This program correctly prints `3`. I assume it means that `*p = z` successfully copied the data of `z` from the stack onto the heap.

If it is possible so easily to copy things from the stack to the heap, why do most people use `memcpy` when attempting to do this? [(E.g. this SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322955/c-copy-struct-with-pointers-from-stack-to-heap/49323149).

In what situations is `memcpy` appropriate, versus in what situations is the above solution okay?

Comment: it is a valid code. you can assign one object of a structure to another object of the sane structure. memcpy is used when for example there are no objects of a structure or you need to do a "deep" copy.

Comment: The choice between assignment and `memcpy` is just individual style, there's no significant reason for it.

Comment: But if it's an array rather than a single object, you need to use `memcpy` because you can't assign arrays.

Comment: @Barmar No, it has nothing common with a style.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `memcpy()` doesn't do a deep copy. It just copies bytes of the top-level object.

Comment: @Barmar Again you are wrong. A structure can contain a data member of a pointer type. So you may not just assign this data member.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Both assignment and memcpy will copy the pointer the same way. `memcpy()` doesn't recurse.

Comment: @Barmar I have not say that you need to use memcpy to copy pointers. It is your fantasy.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow maybe I'm wrong, but I think barmar means that you can't assign using to arrays using the equal operator: `char arr[6]; arr = "Hello";`

Comment: FWIW, there is no point in using `z` in that code. `*p = {.a = 2, .b = 3};` will work fine, and it's one fewer copies (although the compiler should eliminate both `z` and the copy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `memcpy` when you're copying the contents of one array to another (and those contents do not constitute a *string*), or when you're trying to map the contents of an object of one type onto the bytes of an object of a different type.

For example, if you're mapping your `struct` type onto an array of `unsigned char`, you'd do something like:

```
X foo = {1, 2};
unsigned char *bytes = malloc( sizeof foo );
unsigned char sbytes[sizeof foo];

memcpy( bytes, &foo, sizeof foo );
memcpy( sbytes, &foo, sizeof foo );
```

Similarly, if you're trying to copy the contents of one array to another and those contents do not constitute a *string*, you'd also use memcpy:

```
int src[N];
int *dst = malloc( sizeof src );
int sdst[N];
...
memcpy( dst, src, sizeof src );
memcpy( sdst, src, sizeof src );
```

If they do constitute a string, you'd use `strcpy`:

```
char blah[10];
strcpy( blah, "foo" );
```

Otherwise, use the assignment operator as you've done here.

Comment: Are the two options _computionally_ the same? I can say that in embedded environment the direct assignment is really uncommon (to say the least).

Comment: @RobertoCaboni: I don't have an embedded system handy to play with.  I just womped up a simple test that used both `memcpy` and direct assignment to copy a `struct` type with two `int` members, and `gcc` generated the same code for both - it replaced the `memcpy` call with a direct assignment (which makes sense, since both operands are the same type in this case).

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the helpful answer. Two questions: 1. Pretty sure I know this, but it's fair to say that the only difference between `memcpy` and `strcpy` is that the latter doesn't take a specified size to copy, but terminates at the first encountered NULL byte. Correct? 2. *"... map the contents of an object of one type onto the bytes of an object of a different type ..."* - interesting, can you give an example of that? It's unclear to me. Thank you!

Comment: @AvivCohn: 1.  Right - `strcpy` is used to copy strings between arrays of character type - it's a special case of `memcpy`.  2.  Look at my first example, where I map the bytes of `foo` onto an array of `unsigned char`.  As another example, you could copy the bytes of a `float` to a `long` - `strcpy( &long_object, &float_object, sizeof  long_object);` - which preserves the bit pattern of the `float` object in the `long` object (a direct assignment would convert the *value* from a `float` to a `long` representation - i.e., `3.0` => `3`)

Comment: Just for my curiosity, regarding the copy bit-pattern of float into long example, can you give an example of a real world scenario where you would need to do something like this?

Comment: @AvivCohn: Not a good one, really - it's not something I do as a matter of course.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is it good practice to copy objects from the stack to the heap by setting a dereferenced pointer?"

Yes.  `*p = z;` is good.  Benefit over `memcpy()`: type checking.

> In what situations is `memcpy` appropriate, versus in what situations is the above solution okay?

- `memcpy`: When copying an array
- `memcpy`: When the source/destination is not aligned (code needs to pack/unpack data).
- Else: use simply assignment.